# worth installing Jupiter on Acer Apire Revo?

Tags: power-management, jupiter

Would it be worth installing Jupiter (power and device control) on my Acer Aspire Revo net-top ?  Would it help my system any or make a difference ?

Answer (score 1):

i installed jupiter on my dell lattitude and it sure helps a lot. i can now easily change the performance mode to power saving to increase battery life. moreover it has an option to turn wifi on and off which is really a boon to me coz my hardware switch is sometimes not detected by ubuntu